# Macbuntu ppa value error

Tags: 18.04, apt, 64-bit, ppa, macbuntu

I am trying to install Macbuntu on 18.04 Beaver. The first step is to add the Macbuntu PPA repo, this is what happened:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
 This PPA is dedicated to Macbuntu transformation pack for Ubuntu.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/macbuntu
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                 
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu bionic InRelease       
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wxformbuilder/release/ubuntu bionic InRelease   
Ign:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wxformbuilder/wxwidgets/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic InRelease [15.4 kB]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wxformbuilder/release/ubuntu bionic Release    
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/wxformbuilder/wxwidgets/ubuntu bionic Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release [87.9 kB]
Ign:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en
Get:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [10.3 kB]
Err:14 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages
  File has unexpected size (1566644 != 10264). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:10264 [weak]
   - SHA256:98ae801fc0f1337db90fed36d7aae8449dd2801293bb420bc225d78af52e4b73
   - SHA1:3cc40fc32442b8053fd3dc59316ad5b062f08235 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:90b17f6d861636569307c66be6e294b2 [weak]
  Release file created at: Tue, 25 May 2021 16:28:45 +0000
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [10.3 kB]
Err:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  
Get:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [4,588 B]
Err:16 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en
  
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release.gpg [819 B]   
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wxformbuilder/release/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wxformbuilder/wxwidgets/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Conflicting distribution: http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease (expected bionic-updates but got bionic)
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from 'Ubuntu' to 'LP-PPA-danielrichter2007-grub-customizer'
E: Repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu bionic InRelease' changed its 'Label' value from 'Ubuntu' to 'Launchpad PPA for Grub Customizer'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
E: Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security Release' changed its 'Suite' value from 'bionic-updates' to 'bionic-security'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
```

Please help me.

Comment: I see that the `macbuntu` repo added fine.  I see a bunch of other repos that are having issues.  You probably need to fix those, but you should be able to install the MacBuntu that you are after.

Comment: The emphasis here is on the repo get errors AND the Release file / value change errors.